# custom module generating 500 error

Tags: module, addtocart, custom

I have created a custom module to add a custom column to sales_flat_quote and sales_flat_order. I have been successful in creating the columns in the database. The problem is the module also has a observer for event controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index, but when the event is triggered i get 500 error message, and no error details is displayed.

**/app/code/local/JestaSoft/AddTripId/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <modules>
            <JestaSoft_AddTripId>
                    <version>0.1.0</version>
            </JestaSoft_AddTripId>
        </modules>
    <global>
            <resources>
                    <jestasoft_addtripid_setup>
                        <setup>
                                <module>JestaSoft_AddTripId</module>
                        </setup>
                        <connection>
                                <use>core_setup</use>
                        </connection>
                    </jestasoft_addtripid_setup>
            </resources>
            <fieldsets>
                <sales_convert_quote>
                    <trip_id>
                            <to_order>*</to_order>
                        </trip_id>
                </sales_convert_quote>

                <sales_convert_order>
                        <trip_id>
                            <to_order>*</to_order>
                        </trip_id>
                </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>

            <events>
                <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
                        <observers>
                            <jestasoft_addtripid>
                                    <class>JestaSoft_AddTripId_Model_Observer</class>
                                    <method>addTripId</method>
                            </jestasoft_addtripid>
                        </observers>
                </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
            </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/JestaSoft/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

public function addTripId(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $item = $observer->getQuote();
    $tripId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getNTripId();
    $item->setTripId($tripId);
    $item->save();
    return $this;
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you check your server error log, the error should be there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observer should be as below:

```
<?php
class JestaSoft_AddTripId_Model_Observer
{
  public function addTripId(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $item = $observer->getQuote();
    $tripId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getNTripId();
    $item->setTripId($tripId);
    $item->save();
    return $this;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Looking through error logs, previously I was getting unexpected public. After making the changes, I am getting setTripId() on null. How do I get the current quote object in the observer.

Comment: I have tried getQuote and also getQuoteItem both seem to return null

Answer (score 0):

`controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` does *not give you  Quote object.So ,you need to **get Quote object from session** `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()` and set value at Quote

Also,your observer`(Observer.php)` file should be located at JestaSoft/AddTripId/Model/
**So,your observer should be:**

```
<?php
class JestaSoft_AddTripId_Model_Observer{
public function addTripId(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $Quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $tripId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getNTripId();
    $Quote->setTripId($tripId);
    $Quote->save();
    return $this;
}
}
?>
```